# Java postfix calculator. Cannot push to stack?

Tags: java, calculator

I am trying to make a postfix calculator in Java. I am using a Java stack. Everything seems to work fine except that I seem to be unable to push onto the stack. Here is my method that would push to the stack and calculate the given equations:

```
    private void jButtonEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //Postfix calculations done here
    Stack<String> jStack = new Stack<>();
    String field = jTextField1.getText();
    char ch = 0;

     for (int c = 0; c < field.length(); c++)
     {
         ch = field.charAt(c);
         System.out.println(field );
         System.out.println(ch );

         //check for an integer, if its valid, push it onto stack
         if (ch >= 0 && ch <= 9)
         {
             System.out.println("pushing an integer to the stack." );
             jStack.push(Character.toString(ch));
         }

         //check for operators and calculate accordingly
         else if( Character.toString(ch) == "+" )
       {
            System.out.println("popping from stack" );
            int rVal = Integer.parseInt(jStack.pop());
            int lVal = Integer.parseInt(jStack.pop()); 
            jStack.push(Integer.toString(rVal + lVal));
         }

         else if( Character.toString(ch) == "-" )
       {

            int rVal = Integer.parseInt(jStack.pop());
            int lVal = Integer.parseInt(jStack.pop()); 
            jStack.push(Integer.toString(lVal - rVal));
         }

         else if( Character.toString(ch) == "*" )
       {

            int rVal = Integer.parseInt(jStack.pop());
            int lVal = Integer.parseInt(jStack.pop()); 
            jStack.push(Integer.toString(rVal * lVal));
         }

         else if( Character.toString(ch) == "/" )
       {

            int rVal = Integer.parseInt(jStack.pop());
            int lVal = Integer.parseInt(jStack.pop()); 
            jStack.push(Integer.toString(lVal / rVal));

         } else {                  
        //
      }
    }
     if ( !jStack.empty())
     {
        String result = jStack.pop();
        System.out.println( result );
        jTextField1.setText(result);
     }
     else {
         System.out.println( "Your stack is empty and it shouldnt be." );
     }
}
```

No matter what I enter, I always get the message that my stack is empty at the end, and none of my Prints trigger that tell me it is pushing or popping. Have I missed some vital step?

Comment: You've already got a `char`. Don't turn it into a `String` for the comparison, just do `else if (ch == '+')`.

Comment: That did it, Thank you! Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: your code is still broken. `if (ch >= 0 && ch <= 9)` should be `if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')`. Right now you're not adding any digits into stack

Comment: Yes, I realized that and was able to fix that as well, thank you.